# Error while trying to get the log4net log file path in C#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, log4net, log4net-configuration

I'm coming across this error while trying to retrieve the log4net log file path in C#.
This is the code I used.

```
Hierarchy hierarchy = LogManager.GetRepository() as Hierarchy; // WORKS FINE
Logger logger = hierarchy.Root;                                // WORKS FINE
FileAppender appender = logger.Appenders[0] as FileAppender;   // ERROR!!! - Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. [0] Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
string file = appender.File;
```

It seems that there are no Appender objects in the array mentioned above.
Has anyone come accross this?

My log4net config section from App.config:

```xml
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>

<log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender,log4net" >
        <param name="File" value="C:\\SampleLog\\log.txt" />
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <priority value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <category name="Sample.Form1">
        <priority value="ALL" />
    </category>
</log4net>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is that you haven't loaded your configuration.  Have you called `XmlConfigurator.Configure()`?

If so, are you executing the code in question before that call?  Maybe it's as simple as that.